# Java: Image as toggle button

Tags: java, swing

How can I create in a Swing interface a toggle image button?
I have two images, imageon.jpg and imageoff.jpg,and I basically want a clickable element that toggles the images and fires an event.

Update: Is there a way to override the usual 'chrome' around the image? I would prefer a simple image to a button with an image inside.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load the images with `ImageIcon`. Create a `JToggleButton`. Then apply the icons with `AbstractButton.setIcon/setPressedIcon/setSelectedIcon`. Remove the border with `AbstractButton.setBorderPainted(false)`.

Comment: Mmm, forgot about those methods. (And they don't show up in the Javadoc unless you remember they exist.) +1

Comment: really strange... i also tried to make the borderpainted to false but still have the border on the image, nor the toggle. How to solve it out? :(

Answer (score 3):

How about [`JToggleButton`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html)? You can subclass it and override `paint()` to paint the correct image based on whether it is selected or not.

Another way would be to subclass `JPanel` and catch mouse clicks, overriding `paintComponent()` to draw the correct image. This way the only thing that gets drawn is the actual image (unlike the `JToggleButton` option).

Comment: Thanks for the JPanel tip!
I found this resource, hope it teaches me to build what i need:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with JButtons. Try this:

```
result = new JButton( icon );
result.setBorderPainted( false );
result.setContentAreaFilled( false );

width = icon.getIconWidth();
height = icon.getIconHeight();
result.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( width, height ) );
```

It is necessary to set the preferred size to get rid of additional space around the button. This worked for me on Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to subclass AbstractButton, and set properties like border and background (in your constructor).

```
MyButton() {
    setBorder(null);
    setBackground(null);
    }
```